Is it legal to use a model found on github for a personal project and uploading the personal project onto github?
I found a great model I would like to use and make improvements upon for a personal project. It doesn't contain any liscenses nor does it mention anything about restrictions of use.
Are AI models like usually legal to use personal projects and uploading the projects to github?

for all legal matters, please consult a lawyer in your judication.

The best thing to do is to ask the author.

I'd echo @lpounng's comment. But also, for the specific case of "no license, on github," there's this: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1720

Yes -- I do this all the time, even in commercial contexts. For a personal project you are fine. Happy building!
Even my AI product says it's fine :).
https://us.idyllic.app/question/Is-it-legal-to-use-a-model-found-on-github-for-a-personal-project-and-uploading-the-personal-
